# R segmented regression predict error: 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, piecewise

I'm using the segmented package to build a arima regression model with a fair number of predictors. But the model prediction step always gives me this error:

```
Error in matrix(x.values, nrow = n, ncol = k, byrow = FALSE) : 
'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

My code is below. Y_c is the predictand. The X_c is a big matrix of predictors, and X_v is essentially the same matrix but in the validation period. One of the predictors in X_c is TP, and it has two breakpoints. Because I do not want to attach data, I used an isolated variable, and the estimation seems okay.

```
  fit0 = arima( Y_c, order=c(2,0,1), xreg = data.frame(X_c) )
  TP = X_c[,"TP"]
  fitS = segmented.Arima( fit0, seg.Z = ~ TP, psi = c(12,17) )
  predict.segmented(fitA, newdata=data.frame(X_v) )
```

But the last step throws me the error.

I could not find out what I did wrong with the actual data. Testing with dummy data was fine.

```
  x = data.frame( x1=c(1:500), x2 = rnorm(n=500, sd = 30) )
  y = x$x1[1:250] * 2 + x$x1[251:500] /2 + x$x2 /2 + 
      arima.sim( list(ar=c(0.5,0.3), ma=c(0.8)), n = 500 )
  ar_model = arima(y, order=c(2,0,1), xreg=x)
  x1 = x$x1
  seg_model = segmented(ar_model, seg.Z=~x1, psi=c(400), 
              control=seg.control(display=FALSE, K=1, random=TRUE))
  predict.segmented(seg_model, data.frame(x1=c(1:500),x2=c(1:500)))
```

This is really frustrating. If anyone can give some help it will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at `data.frame(X_v)`. It's probably not what you think it is. At least, it is not what the function expects.